# Something similar to Grails Domain properties field in Spring?

Tags: spring, grails, properties, bind

I have started a new project in Spring Boot after using Grails for 4 years. 
In Grails I have used properties field of an instance of a domain class to update the associate row in a db table. The assignment of domain.properties was usually done inside a service.
The `properties` field was set with data coming from a web form. 
This approach allows to update a domain instance with a single line, instead of writing n assignemnt, where n is the number of the attributes defined in the domain class.

Now the question.. there is something similar in Spring? 
I would like to do something similar in Spring:

```
update(Long radioId,Map properties) {
      // get the radio to be update from the db
      Radio radio = getRadio(radioId) 
      radio.properties = properties 
      save(radio)
}
```

I add some detail,
My controller

```
public ModelAndView updateRadio(Radio radio) {
        radioService.update(radio);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/superadmin/radio/"+radio.getIdentifier()+"/zoom");
    }
```

My Service

```
@Service
public class RadioService {
...

    public void update(Radio radio) {
            assert radio.getId() != null;
            radioRepository.save(radio);
    }
...
}
```

Now if the web form does not explicity send all the fields defined in Radio I have problem since I will loose the value of the field already stored.
If I could write somthing like that

```
public void update(Map radioProperties,Long radioId) {
  Radio radio = radioRepository.findById(radioId);
  radio.properties = radioProperties // only properties present in this map will be update (in grails)
  radioRepository.save(radio);
}
```

it would be great.
In the latter method only the properties in the map (ence in the web form) will be updated, and the other store field of the radio instance will be untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/), it can load domain objects by id, bind incoming request parameters to domain objects and also automagic you some CRUD repositories.

Comment: Hi, I'm alread using Spring Data JPA. I have updated my question with more detail hoping to be  clearer. Thx

Comment: Ah, sorry, I've always handled this front-end e.g. using hidden fields or server-side by using @InitBinder for more complex binding. Maybe Spring's BeanUtils can help you - http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html

Comment: Ok thanks, I would check it.. but It seems I have to implement by my self. :-)